# Change the text style of references to line numbers in listings

Tags: hyperref, listings, labels, cleveref, ref

Consider the following document:

```
% Document
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% Packages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks, 
    citecolor = blue, 
    filecolor = blue, 
    linkcolor = blue, 
    urlcolor = blue
]{hyperref}
% Contents
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{sec:first}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[
    language = C++,
    escapechar = `,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    showstringspaces = false,
    keywordstyle = \color{blue},
    commentstyle = \color{red},
]
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;`\label{lst:line}`
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
This is a reference to section \ref{sec:first}.
This is a reference to line \ref{lst:line}.
\end{document}
```

I would like the reference to the line number in the listing (and only this type of reference) to appear just as regular text (not colored) in `\texttt{}`. I am ok to define a `\newcommand{\coderef}[1]{...#1...}` to make that happen (with `...` being replace with the appropriate commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following macro appears to do what you want. It is based on `\ref*` to retrieve the reference text without generating a hyperlink, since `\hyperref` will itself create a hyperlink. As expected, the resulting text is a hyperlink to the reference indicated by the argument.

```latex
\newcommand*{\coderef}[1]{%
  \colorlet{currcol}{.}% retrieve the current color (.)
  \hyperref[#1]{\textcolor{currcol}{\texttt{\ref*{#1}}}}%
}
```

Another possibility is to use `\getrefbykeydefault` from the `refcount` package to retrieve the reference text without the link. This way, you can even choose what is printed when the needed information is not in the `.aux` file yet (here, I use the standard `??`):

```latex
\newcommand*{\coderef}[1]{%
  \colorlet{currcol}{.}% retrieve the current color (.)
  \refused{#1}%
  \hyperref[#1]{\textcolor{currcol}{\texttt{%
    \getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{??}}}}%
}
```

Full code using the `\ref*` method (both give the same output):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks,
    citecolor = blue,
    filecolor = blue,
    linkcolor = blue,
    urlcolor = blue
]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\coderef}[1]{%
  \colorlet{currcol}{.}% retrieve the current color (.)
  \hyperref[#1]{\textcolor{currcol}{\texttt{\ref*{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}\label{sec:first}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[
    language = C++,
    escapechar = `,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    showstringspaces = false,
    keywordstyle = \color{blue},
    commentstyle = \color{red},
]
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;`\label{lst:line}`
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
This is a reference to section \ref{sec:first}.
This is a reference to line \coderef{lst:line}.

\textcolor{red!40!black}{%
  Now with \texttt{red!40!black} as the ambiant text color:
  the line containing \texttt{std::cout} is line~\coderef{lst:line}.%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]